# Youtube API v3 - get info from a video

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

For my project i need to get title, rating and category for some video add by users in my website, how i can do this ?

I tried to use API YouTube Data and the getRating, create project in google developers console, enabled the YouTube Data API v3 and create public key but always same error :

> There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.

Who can explain me please ? 
Thanks

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

When you created your public API key you're allowed to filter requests to allow by IP or by Referer. Sounds like you typed something in there so your IP or Referer url should match it or else you get your error message above. The filter should be empty to allow any requests.

Check your filter by going to your project page -> APIs & Auth -> Credentials

For instance, mine has

```
Key for browser applications
REFERERS  Any referer allowed
```